# in jquery datatables i want to give url if zero records found for new entry

Tags: datatable, datatables, jquery-data

in jquery datatables i want to give url if zero records found for new entry..

```js
$('#datatables').dataTable({
    "language": {
         "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
         "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - Do you want Register? Click Here _URL_",
         "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
         "infoEmpty": "No records available",
         "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
});
```

so where in zerorecord  in *URL* i want to give url for new entry..

Answer (score 1):

sorry i found my answer!

```js
$('#datatables').dataTable({
    "language": {
       "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
       "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - Do you want Register? <a href=#>Click Here</a>",
       "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
       "infoEmpty": "No records available",
       "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
});
```